# how to resolve The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago in google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

I develop application in google app engine with jpa 
my application work fine in localhost 
so I uploaded my application to production and after some queries like (select or insert) on database I get this error for each operation 
"The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago in google app engine"
if I reset the data base or upload the project again it is working for some few more queries (10-15 queries) , but then I get the error again

my code to EntityManagerFactory

```
    if (SystemProperty.environment.value() ==  SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url",System.getProperty("cloudsql.url"));
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver",System.getProperty("cloudsql.classname.prod"));
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user",System.getProperty("cloudsql.user.prod"));
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password",System.getProperty("cloudsql.password.prod"));
    } else {
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url",System.getProperty("cloudsql.url.dev"));
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver",System.getProperty("cloudsql.classname.dev"));
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user",System.getProperty("cloudsql.user.dev"));
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password",System.getProperty("cloudsql.password.dev"));
    }
```

my code to insert

```
public Base insert(Base base){
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    try{
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        base.setLastUpdated(getCoreServer().getTimeManager().getCurrentTime());
        em.persist(base);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        return base;
    }
    finally{
        em.close();
    }
}
```

I know there are a lot of topics on this error but I try to found answer in google but it is not working

Thank you

Comment: I am also getting this with Java, MySQL and JPA but I am not using Google's AppEngine. I too have a certain number of queries that work fine and then the next one doesn't. Didn't count but 10/15 sounds about right.